# C++ Integration Solution using Riemann Sum : Loses validity for greater than 10 partitions

Tags: c++, integral

In an effort to code the briefest solution I could for an approximation of the integral using Riemann sums, I ran into a strange problem: if the user requested a partition count in excess of 10, the program failed. Any thoughts? Here's the code:

```
// The Integral

#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cin;     using std::cout;
using std::endl;    

int func (int x);

int main () 
{   
    cout << "Please enter left and right bounds: ";

    int left, right;
    cin >> left >> right;

    cout << "Please enter a # of partitions (>0): ";

    int R;
    cin >> R;

    int width = (right - left) / R;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
        total += func(left + width*i);
    }   

    cout << "The integral is: " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}

int func (int x) 
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std` would save you from writing all those using statements. Just a thought.

Comment: @Alex: Ironically, `using namespace std;` is generally considered poor practice.

Comment: If everyone else said it was poor practice to not jump off a cliff, would you?

Answer (score 6):

Using a partition size of greater than 10 is not your actual problem.

Your are using integers for your variables and function return value, when you should be using `float` or `double`.

For instance:

```
int width = (right - left) / R;
```

If `(right - left) < R` width will be zero!

Answer (score 3):

on a side note, unless you plan on expanding this small prog, you're including way to many useless stuff. this is all you'd need for this prog:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int func (int x) 
{
    return x*x;
}

int main()
{
// if you have your main() at the bottom, you dont have to declare other functions on top.
}
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Another comment:

In my opinion the for-loop in your code does not compute the correct Riemann-sum.
I think it should look like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
     total += func(left) * width;
     left += width;
   }
```

Cheers :)